# How to convert 'DataFrameGroupBy' to DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have data, that I want to calculate a mean of 5 rows and later create a new table.
Example data:

```
,speed_desired,ambient_temperature,ambient_pressure,speed,temperature,pressure
0,1000,19.91,100.98,560.42,148.39,182.19
1,1000,20.03,101.02,843.28,148.37,448.47
2,1000,20.05,100.92,983.12,148.4,675.49
3,1000,20.07,101.0,1052.37,148.24,845.42
4,1000,20.05,100.98,1086.29,148.35,969.79
5,1000,19.93,100.93,1107.29,148.43,1079.25
6,1000,20.06,100.98,1112.75,148.28,1110.86
7,1000,20.0,101.08,1119.72,148.32,1117.46
8,1000,19.94,100.96,1119.33,148.26,1139.64
9,1000,19.94,101.01,1118.8,148.25,1173.16
10,1000,20.05,101.05,1119.16,148.37,1162.44
11,1000,20.0,100.92,1115.65,148.29,1183.07
12,1000,19.97,101.02,1122.59,148.36,1177.44
13,1000,20.1,101.0,1124.66,148.44,1164.61
14,1000,19.99,100.91,1123.38,148.41,1165.45
15,1000,19.96,100.99,1125.05,148.42,1156.23
16,1000,20.06,101.07,1116.51,148.33,1184.12
17,1000,20.1,101.01,1117.51,148.29,1154.25
18,1000,20.03,101.02,1118.27,148.26,1160.29
19,1000,19.92,101.07,1123.47,148.35,1184.8
```

So I found that I can use this

```
X_data = X_data.groupby(np.arange(len(X_data)) // 5).mean()
```

And it somehow works (I just don't get two decimals places).

```
0,1000.0,20.0015,100.99666666666667,1102.1871666666666,148.36433333333335,1117.258
1,1000.0,20.003333333333334,100.99033333333334,1120.6831666666667,148.43883333333332,1164.5089999999998
2,1000.0,19.995,100.99233333333333,1120.874,148.54183333333333,1160.0673333333332
3,1000.0,19.988833333333332,100.99600000000001,1119.3431666666665,148.61316666666667,1164.961
```

y_data look like this:

```
0,M_0003
1,M_0005
2,M_0007
3,M_0003
```

But later when I want to use this data.

```
variable_params = {'max_depth': [2, 4, 6, 10], 'n_estimators': [5, 10, 20, 25],
                   'learning_rate': np.linspace(1e-16, 1, 3)}
static_params = {'objective': 'multi:softmax', 'num_class': 6, 'silent': 1}

bst_grid = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=XGBClassifier(**static_params),
    param_grid=variable_params,
    scoring="accuracy"
)

bst_grid.fit(X_data, y_data)

print("Best Accuracy:{}".format(bst_grid.best_score_))
for key, value in bst_grid.best_params_.items():
    print("{}:{}".format(key, value))
```

I get this error:

```
Expected array-like (array or non-string sequence), got <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x000001F3B2F17760>
```

Is there a way to convert this data?
Or maybe there is a better way to calculate the mean?

Comment: You did something wrong, your command should give you a DataFrame of 4 rows

Comment: I want the mean of each column. The output should be 4 rows with each having the mean of 5 rows.

Comment: ok you say 5 rows, what 5 rows?

Comment: I added the output, how it look like now

Comment: okay, how are you trying to use the outputted variable afterwards?

Comment: I want to use it for GridSearchCV

Comment: the output of the mean X_data works exactly as expected. I think you'd need to post the code where you're using GridSearchCV and the dataframe together for us to help you with that part.

Comment: btw you can convert to 2 decimal places with np.round: X_data = np.round(X_data, decimals=2)

Comment: I added code and y_data

Comment: The code can't reproduce that error, so it is not complete I think

Comment: may I ask, where do you get the raw data from in the start? is it .csv, or .txt or what?
asking, as you may read data into dataframe directly without any `focus pocus` codes

Comment: It is from .csv file

Comment: have you tried `df = pd.read_csv(filename.csv)` ? and move from there

Answer (score 0):

I would start from something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

step = 5
X_data  = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Test\test.csv")

df = X_data.groupby(X_data.index // step).mean()
print(df)

   speed_desired  ambient_temperature  ...  temperature  pressure
0         1000.0               20.022  ...      148.350   624.272
1         1000.0               19.974  ...      148.308  1124.074
2         1000.0               20.022  ...      148.374  1170.602
3         1000.0               20.014  ...      148.330  1167.938
```

Comment: P.S. I noticed you had another question (on another thread) on how to get unique values of `M_0003`...
Maybe... it is better to combine data from both sources and group/get mean later...
you should share both raw data examples and the result you want to achieve.